# Compression of Binary file

Tags: algorithm, compression

If we are given a binary file of length n, where each bit independently is one with probability 1/3 and zero else. We want to construct a method that the expected length of the compressed sequence is less than 10 percent more than Shannon's lower bound (for all n large enough).
    I've got the lower bound is 0.918. I tried to use tuples of size 2, but it gives me an expected length of 1.88 by Huffman coding. Am I going in the right direction?

- What if we want to get a 3% margin ?

Comment: Please provide some code :)

Comment: "length of 1.88" already means that you use only 0.94 bits per bit. You can get closer e.g. by using larger tuples.

Comment: By using a tuple of 3, it seems I get a larger expected length than 1.88

Answer (score 2):

The Shannon entropy bound is 0.918 output bits per input bit.

If you just write the bits you're given, you'll spend 1 output bit per input bit.

This is *already* less than 10% more than the bound, so no compression is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Arithmetic compressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) or [Rangecoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_encoding).

There is explanation with code for [Arithmetic compressor](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/data-compression-with-arithmetic-encodin/240169251) and open-source implementation of [Rangecoder](https://github.com/kazuho/rangecoder).

I personally recommend to use Rangecoder, because of it works fastest, and has never been patented (patent for arithmetic compressor already expired).

Comment: I see! Thank you so much